# Calculate points with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm stuck on how to get to my destination.
I have students points. I'd like to code it so that out of the total subjects, a students points can only be calculated out of a selected 4 subjects. The first 2 subjects are compulsory. Out of the remaining , you have to choose one between 'BIO' and 'PHY' depending on which is higly scored.
Out of the remaining three subjects, you can only choose 1, either 'GEO','CRE' or 'HIS' depending on which is highly scored.

This is what I have coded, doesn't give me my result.

```
sums = df['ENG']+df['KIS']+df['BIO']+df['PHY']+df['HIS']+df['GEO']+df['CRE']
if 'BIO' >='PHY':
    sum = (sums) - (df['PHY'])
else:
    sum = (sums) - (df['BIO'])
if 'GEO'>='CRE':
    sum = (sums) - (df['CRE'])
else:
    sum = (sums) - (df['GEO'])
if 'CRE'>='HIS':
    sum = (sums) - (df['CRE'])
else:
    sum = (sums) - (df['HIS'])
df['POINTS'] = sum
print(df)
```

Sample data is here.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ENG':[10,3,5,6,3],'KIS':[9,5,7,9,10],'BIO':[11,3,4,6,4],'PHY':[5,3,9,10,2],'HIS':[7,12,9,7,8],'GEO':[2,7,6,11,7],'CRE':[8,3,6,8,10]})
```

Based on this data an expected outcome would be

```
   ENG  KIS  BIO  PHY  HIS  GEO  CRE  POINTS
   10    9   11    5    7    2    8      38
    3    5    3    3   12    7    3      23
    5    7    4    9    9    6    6      30
    6    9    6   10    7   11    8      36
    3   10    4    2    8    7   10      27
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use the [`.max(axis=1)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.max.html) operation and `+` the results.

```py
df['POINTS'] = df['ENG'] + df['KIS'] + df[['BIO', 'PHY']].max(axis=1) + df[['HIS', 'GEO', 'CRE']].max(axis=1)

 ENG  KIS  BIO  PHY  HIS  GEO  CRE  POINTS
  10    9   11    5    7    2    8      38
   3    5    3    3   12    7    3      23
   5    7    4    9    9    6    6      30
   6    9    6   10    7   11    8      36
   3   10    4    2    8    7   10      27
```

Comment: Thanks, simply fast and direct

Comment: @user13543235 Glad to help. If you're using pandas and find yourself attempting a lot of convoluted logic or using loops, that's probably not the correct approach.  Just an FYI.  Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

In order to take the sum you need to take use aggregation functions in pandas :

```
  sums = df['ENG'].sum()+df['KIS'].sum()+df['BIO'].sum()+df['PHY'].sum()+df['HIS'].sum()+df['GEO'].sum()+df['CRE'].sum()
```

That way you will have sums of all the items in the `sums` variable and than in your if condition each one would be like :

```
  sum = (sums) - (df['BIO'].sum())
```

So all your if conditions would look like this :

```
 if df['BIO'].sum() >= df['PHY'].sum():
   sum = (sums) - (df['PHY'].sum())
 else:
   sum = (sums) - (df['BIO'].sum())
 if df['GEO'].sum() >= df['CRE'].sum():
   sum = (sums) - (df['CRE'].sum())
 else:
   sum = (sums) - (df['GEO'].sum())
 if df['CRE'].sum() >= df['HIS'].sum():
   sum = (sums) - (df['CRE'].sum())
 else:
   sum = (sums) - (df['HIS'].sum())
 df['POINTS'] = sum
 print(df)
```

This is based on what I understood, I am not sure if you are comparing the sums or just individual values.