# How to choose items out of many options in pandas

Tags: pandas

This question [Calculate points with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61803635/13543235) did not capture well what I wanted to ask so I ask it here.
I have this data here

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ENG':[10,3,5,6,3],'KIS':[9,5,7,9,10],'BIO':[10,'',4,'',4],'PHY':[9,5,'',10,12],'HIS':['','',9,7,8],'GEO':['',7,'',11,''],'CRE':[8,3,6,'','']})
```

My program is to calculate the points for every individual in the data choosing only 4 subjects out of the 5 done.
The first two subjects are compulsories. In order to get the other two subjects to add to get the 4 required, you weigh between the remaining subjects, in which you pick the best performed.

My expected outcome looks like this.

```
   ENG  KIS BIO PHY HIS GEO CRE  POINTS
   10    9   10   9           8    38
    3    5       5       7   3     20
    5    7   4       9       6     27
    6    9      10   7  11         36
    3   10   4  12   8             25
```

This is what I tried

```
a = df['ENG'] + df['KIS'] + df[['BIO', 'PHY']].fillna(0).max(axis=1) + df[['HIS', 'GEO', 'CRE']].fillna(0).max(axis=1) 
df['POINTS'] = a
print(df)
```

Comment: are the blanks in your data actually the empty strings `''`?

Comment: So ENG and KIS are the compulsories?

Comment: the blanks are actually blank. The students do not do them

Comment: @cmosing, 4 the two compulsories and other two

Comment: Your input and output dataframes don't match in your question. Can you create  verifiable example?

Comment: Your supplied dataframe does not match the dataframe in the expected outcome. E.g. bio is 10,4,4 but in the expected outcome it is 7,4,4

Comment: @Scott Boston, checked and sorted

Comment: Result in first row should be 38.

Comment: @cmosig, thanks I saw and corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort each row by value and then pick the best two and sum them:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ENG':[10,3,5,6,3],'KIS':[9,5,7,9,10],'BIO':[10,'',4,'',4],'PHY':[9,5,'',10,12],'HIS':['','',9,7,8],'GEO':['',7,'',11,''],'CRE':[8,3,6,'','']})
df = df.replace('',0)
df[['BIO','PHY','HIS','GEO','CRE']].apply(lambda row: row.sort_values(ascending=False).head(2).sum() ,axis=1) + df['ENG'] + df['KIS']

0    38
1    20
2    27
3    36
4    33
```

Comment: Thanks big. I appreciate this answer.

Comment: No, I had only 15 points then it went back to 13, so it couldn't hold. But there it is.